# Почему не срабатывает callback-функция?

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему у меня не срабатывает callback функция?

```
jQuery(this).click(function () {
    $("#exampleMenu").stop().animate({
        top: '-100%'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 1200,
        easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    }, {
        callback: function () {
            $('#maincolumn').stop().animate({
                top: '0'
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 1200,
                easing: 'easeOutBounce'
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: если при форматирование вашего вопроса никто не потерял фигурную скобку, то следовательно из-за её отсутсвия функция и не работает

Comment: где именно? не могу найти

Comment: ещё раз пересмотрел код - все скобки на месте, странно

Comment: версия библиотеки не имеет значения? я подключил 1.4.2

Answer (score 1):

нет, вы просто как-то не так её объявляете - из [документации](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) следует, что нужно так:

```
    queue: false,
    duration: 1200,
    easing: 'easeOutBounce',
    complete: function () {
        $('#maincolumn').stop().animate({
            top: '0'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 1200,
            easing: 'easeOutBounce'
        })
    }
```